# Erro ao encontrar ROTA com o Método PUT no LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Boa noite estou com um problema em meu código usando o LARAVEL, ao usar uma rota no form essa rota esta retornando a pagina Not Found 404.

```
    <form class="forms-sample" action="/update/{{$controle_ntes -> id}}" method="post">
      @csrf
      @method ('PUT')
```

acima esta a `action` que passo a rota no `form` e abaixo a rota onde teria que entrar nessa rota passada na `action`, tenho outras rotas com o `method` `GET` e esta indo normalmente, só que com o `PUT` nao esta encontrando a rota e dando o erro citado acima.

Rotas:

```
Route::get('/nte/{nte}', [Controle_ntesController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/show/uee/{$id}', [Controle_ntesController::class, 'show']);
Route::put('/update{id}', [Controle_ntesController::class, 'update']);
```

Controller:

```
use App\Models\Controle_nte;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function update(Request $request) {
    
            Controle_nte::findOrFail($request->id) -> update($request -> all());
            return view ('/');
            
        }
```

Model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Controle_nte extends Model {

    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A definição da rota está incorreta, foi esquecida a mágica `/`:

```
Route::put('/update{id}', [Controle_ntesController::class, 'update']);
```

Troque para:

```
Route::put('/update/{id}', [Controle_ntesController::class, 'update']);
```

Para pegar esses erros com praticidade, procure pensar assim:
Se o erro foi 404, é por que a rota que você está tentando chamar não existe, para isso duas coisas podem estar erradas:

1. A definição da rota (como foi este caso);
2. O form onde a rota é chamada.

Em outros casos, você pode receber um `405 Method Not Allowed`, quando a rota existe mas o método está errado.

---

Adicionalmente a este seu tópico, gostaria de lhe recomendar que evite utilizar `$request->all()` para sua segurança, procure sempre validar os dados de entrada e utilizar `$request->validated()` para pegar os dados, isso te previnirá de inserir dados incorretos na base e também lhe deixará mais seguro.

Talvez este vídeo (em inglês) possa contribuir com seu aprendizado:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQS5oEOguRU&t=4s